# Accessing image name from servlet and displaying that image in a JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, image-upload

I am doing an image upload part in home.jsp. after image is uploaded that image should be shown in another jsp page (imageView.jsp).Images are stored inside a folder inside the project path.

home.jsp

```
<form action="UploadServlet" method="post" class=" form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id = "head" class="row " >
                <h4 class="text-center textTitle">Upload an Image to be extracted</h4>
            </div>
            <div id =" imageDisplay " class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-6">


                    <span class="btn btn-image  btn-file pull-right">Upload
                        <input type="file" name="image" id="extractimage">

                    </span>
 </div>
<div  id =" imageDisplay " class=" col-md-6">

<input type="submit" class= "btn btn-image pull-left">Preview</a>
</div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Then user is directed to UploadSErvlet.java which carry out image upload process. 
UploadServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
 Part uploadedImage = request.getPart("image");

        String filename = uploadedImage.getSubmittedFileName();

        out.println(filename);
        InputStream filecontent = uploadedImage.getInputStream();
        imageUpload image = new imageUpload();
        String extnsn = image.getExtensn(filename);
        out.println(extnsn);
        boolean flag = image.imageInputstream(filecontent, extnsn, filename);
        if (flag == true) {
            out.println("<html><body onload=\"alert('Image uploaded successful')\"></body></html>");
        } else {
            out.println("<html><body onload=\"alert('Image not uploaded successful')\"></body></html>");
        }

        //returning name of the image to another jsp page
        request.setAttribute(" name ", filename);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("imageView.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Here after obtaining filename of the uploaded image it should be passed to imageView.jsp page and inside a div that image should be displayed.user should be redirected to imageView.jsp page

imageView.jsp

```
 <%
                String fname = (String) request.getAttribute(" name ");
            %>

            <div class="row">
                <div  id = "display" class="col-lg-8 center-block "><img src="C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Linguist\uploadedImage\<%=fname%>" width="300" height="500" alt="image"/>
```

in the url bar it shows that it's still in the UploadServlet. But imageView.jsp user interface is shown in the screen. But image is not displayed in the div as expected. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you getting file name in `fname` variable??

Comment: yes I used that variable to assign the file name passed from the UploadServlet

Comment: Check the src path exist or not..

Comment: Yes it exist. I even print the name of the image. name is printed. but image doesn't displayed

Comment: You've an XY-problem. You just saved the uploaded image at a completely wrong location. The detailed answer is in the duplicate. Advance from there, it also contains links how to properly show it in JSP. It's at least absolutely not to be done with a local disk file system path.

Comment: How can i find the duplicate answer?

Comment: It's linked in top of your question.